# Dynamically creating buttons in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I created app in Windows Phone 8.1(universal). I need to create a dynamic field of the buttons. This is my example xaml:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid x:Name="_root"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="10" />
```

This is my code:

```
            _root.Children.Clear();
            _root.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            Size = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            {
                _root.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                });
            }
                for (int column = 0; column < Size; column++)
                {
                    Button btnTemp = new Button();
                    btnTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    btnTemp.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    btnTemp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    btnTemp.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    btnTemp.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    btnTemp.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                    btnTemp.Content = column;
                    Grid.SetColumn(btnTemp, column);
                    Grid.SetRow(btnTemp, 0);
                    _root.Children.Add(btnTemp);    
                }
```

It is my result:

[image]

If I used :

```
  Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
```

I get result:

[image]

I need to fix these bugs:

1.Align text to the center of the button.

2. Do not see the right border of the button "4".Button "4" other widely.

Comment: try making width of the grid as auto... and why dont you add a text box to the center dynamically... That would be easier for you.

Comment: I tried used grid column width as auto. The result of the second picture. "Add textBox dynamically" - good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix in your case is quite easy - just define *MinWidth* of created button as `0` (default has some value).

```
btnTemp.MinWidth = 0;
```

I think it should help.

Nevertheless, in your case I wouldn't add buttons to grid, I would probably define *ItemsPanel* and suitable *ItemsTemplate* with *Button*, then bind to a collection.